# How can I change the curly brace style in Xcode 6.1?

Tags: coding-style, xcode6, editor, indentation

There are answers to this question for previous versions of Xcode, but none that satisfy my needs.

By default, Xcode 6.1 defaults to the [K&R style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style) of indentation, but I prefer [Allman style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style). Right now, all my code snippets are Allman style, however Xcode's autocomplete feature for functions that can be implemented still place the brace on the same line as the function declaration. E.g., if I make create a class and write `init` and let Xcode autocomplete, it places the opening brace on the same line. It's not a huge deal to fix it manually, but it is kind of a drag.

How can I achieve this functionality, even if it's hacky?

Comment: I vaguely recall you go into Settings and then Editor settings and you find the option there.  But I don't have an Xcode environment here to check.

Comment: Nope, the option is not there.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same frustration, and developed an AppleScript that helps, to a degree.  Text editing in Xcode is poorly supported via scriptability, so there are a few quirks to my script.  It seems to work best when you have a .swift file open in the Xcode Workspace, and it also seems happier when you have opened the one that you want to edit the curly braces.

It will only correctly indent the class and func level opening curly braces, although all other opening curly braces will be on their own lines.  I typically run it after I have added all the IBActions to clean it up for me.

I store the script in the ~/Library/Scripts/Applications/Xcode folder, so that I can access it easily.

Here it is, and good luck:

```
set oneIndent to space & space & space & space -- Four spaces for indent (see Text Editing Preferences -> Indentation)
set isFirstBrace to true
global oneIndent, isFirstBrace

tell application "Xcode"
    set allDocs to every text document
    set theirNames to the name of every text document
    choose from list theirNames with prompt "Choose your active file:"
    if the result is not false then
        set aName to item 1 of the result
        set c to my FindItemNumber(theirNames, aName)
        set workingDocument to item c of allDocs
        set delegateText to text of workingDocument
        set textParagraphs to every paragraph of delegateText
        set newTextString to {}
        repeat with eachPara in textParagraphs
            if (eachPara as text) contains "{" then
                set end of newTextString to my solveIndent(eachPara as text)
                if isFirstBrace is true then set isFirstBrace to false
            else
                set end of newTextString to (eachPara as text) & return
            end if
        end repeat
        set text of item 1 of workingDocument to (newTextString as text)
    end if
end tell

----------------------
to solveIndent(p)
    set astid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "{"
    if isFirstBrace is true then
        set newParagraph to (text item 1 of p) & return & "{" & (text item 2 of p) & return
    else
        set newParagraph to (text item 1 of p) & return & oneIndent & "{" & (text item 2 of p) & return
    end if
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to astid
    return newParagraph
end solveIndent

--------------------------
to FindItemNumber(lst, choice)
    set counter to 1
    repeat with eachOption in lst
        if choice = (eachOption as text) then
            set cc to counter
            exit repeat
        end if
        set counter to counter + 1
    end repeat
    return cc
end FindItemNumber
```